# viewWillAppear not firing ever again after app enters foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, viewwillappear

When i enter foreground after  viewWillAppear didn't be call can any one guide me how could i fire my viewWillAppear method after foreground

Thanks for advance

Comment: viewWillAppear on what? Which controller? Please add details.

Comment: i have three view controllers so if i am in first view controller then i close app when i come back that viewController will show right?so   how could i say that which controller is appear

Answer (score 2):

In any app when ever your app goes into background or enters foreground your viewController's delegate methods wont be called, your application delegate methods will be called.

Apple has provided notifications for each app delegate methods, you can implement them in your viewControllers where you want to work out on minimize and maximize your app.

Simply use `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` for detecting app entering background and use `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` or `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` for detecting app returning to foreground.

Add and remove these notifications in proper places, mainly add in `viewDidLoad` and remove in `viewDidUnLoad`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find out which view controller is on top in your appdelegate's method:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application{
    /* find out the top view controller as

    self.navigationController.visibleViewController
                 OR
    self.navigationController.topViewController
    and find out its kind using:
    [self.navigationController.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[YourViewControllerClass Class]];
    */
}
```